# Swiper Slides don't Autoplay

Tags: swiper.js

I added a swiper in Shopify by importing swiper-bundle.js and css via cdn (script and styleshett in theme.liquid), then I initialized the swiper in theme.js and everything is working fine.

But When I try to add the autoplay it doesn't work at all.

Here's my codes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9.3.1/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9.3.1/modules/autoplay/autoplay.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9.3.1/modules/autoplay/autoplay.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9.3.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Here I tried to add autoplay modules too, with no luck.

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {

  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: true,
  speed: 500,
  effect: 'fade',
  autoplay: {
   delay: 2000,
 },
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
});
```

```
<div class="flex-container">
<!-- Slider main container -->
  <div class="swiper" >
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
<div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
<div class="swiper-slide"> 
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

</div>


  <div class="text-container">
    
<p>Piece Name</p><p>Text</p>
<a href="">CTA</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!

I tried to import modules, but it gives error. I tried to set autoplay: { enabled: true, } (didn't work). I tried to give each slide a delay, nothing.

Comment: To anyone looking for an answer at this problem. Don't use swiper version 9+. I solved it using 8.0

Comment: Could you elaborate how you got it working particularly the initialisation on Shopify?
I've tried the same and can't get it initialised, or get navigation or pagination working.
Errors on importing modules, so how did you get around that?